# Setting a user role in a request for implementing Role-Based Access for protecting web-service in jersey

Tags: java, web-services, security, http, jersey

I want to implement authorization for my web services and as per the jersey documentation [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/security.html), it can be achieved with role based access. I want to protect a web service and has tried doing it in the following way.

```
@Path("complain")
public Complain get(@Context SecurityContext sc) {
    if (sc.isUserInRole("member") {
        return new complain();
    } else {
        return new error();
    }
}
```

It gets the user role in a request and if it is member then it grants access and if not throws error. But how can I set a user role.

Answer (score 0):

this will help you.

[reference url](http://porterhead.blogspot.in/2013/01/writing-rest-services-in-java-part-6.html)

```
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <url-pattern>/rest/admin/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <url-pattern>/rest/orders/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>customer</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>my-default-realm</realm-name>
    </login-config

>
```

Comment: Using this configuration i can declare which url's should be accessed by which role. I want to set that role so that it can be accessed.